# Sonata default filter value

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata

I have a property in my method `configureDatagridFilters()` called assignee. When the list view of my admin is first loaded, I'd like to set the value of this property to the current user.

I have tried:

```
public function getFilterParameters()
{
    $parameters = parent::getFilterParameters();

    $parameters['assignee'] = [
        'value' => $this->getUser(),
    ];

    return $parameters;
}
```

as well as an `array_merge` instead. None of them achieved what I'm after, it still just shows me the default/entire list.

I have tried adding a type, bit unclear as to what the type is as some examples I've seen are like `EntityType::class` and others just a number `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out how to set the filter by default to the current user.

My filter is an `EntityType::class` with the class of `User::class`. In order for the code snippet above to work, you must set the value to the user ID and not the user object like so: `'value' => $this->getUser()->getId()`.

So the full method would be:

```
public function getFilterParameters()
{
    $parameters = parent::getFilterParameters();

    $parameters['assignee'] = [
        'value' => $this->getUser()->getId(),
    ];

    return $parameters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is kind of wrong. You will not be able to change "asignee" filter - so its not a "default", but "forced filter" behavior. You should add array_key_exists checks to code like

```
public function getFilterParameters()
{
    $parameters = parent::getFilterParameters();

    if (!array_key_exists('assignee', parameters)) {        
        $parameters['assignee'] = [
             'value' => $this->getUser()->getId(),
        ];
    }

    return $parameters;
}
```